# How to Find the Unique Combination of a List of Permutations

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have an array of permutations.

```
var D = [["A","B","C"],["A","C","B"],["B","A","C"],["B","C","A"],["C","A","B"],["C","B","A"]]
```

I want to do the opposite of listing all permutations of a combination. I want to find the unique combination of the permutations using JavaScript.

That unique combination would be

```
unique = [["A","B","C"]]
```

This is just a simple example. I want to find the unique combinations of a larger set of permutations with more elements, but I believe the solution would be scalable.

How do I find the unique combination using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

This may be a solution:

```js
var D = [["A","B","C"],["A","C","B"],["B","A","C"],["B","C","A"],["C","A","B"],["C","B","A"]];

const unique = [...new Map(D.map(i => [i.sort().join(''), i])).values()];

console.log(unique);
```

Comment: Thanks!  That apparently does the trick, even with other permutations included.  How did you come up with that?

Comment: I am just using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) wherever I can :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear what you're asking, but I think it's that you want to find each symbol that occurs in the original list? Will every array within the original list contain the same characters (ie. all sub-arrays in `var D` will only be made up of `"A"`, `"B"`, and `"C"`)?
If so, you could loop through your `D` array and keep track of each element you see in a `Set`, which will automatically de-dupe your output for you:

```js
var D = [["A","B","C"],["A","C","B"],["B","A","C"],["B","C","A"],["C","A","B"],["C","B","A"]]
const uniques = new Set()

for(const arr of D) {
    for(const c of arr)  {
        uniques.add(c)
    }
}

console.log(uniques) // -> Set(3) {'A', 'B', 'C'}
```

Then, if that specific output format is needed, you can convert the set with something like

```js
const arr = []
for(const c of uniques) {
    arr.push(c)
}
const result = [ arr ]
console.log(result) // -> [['A', 'B', 'C']]
```